# Keep last keyframes and delete the others

Tags: python, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have a script that run a rigid body simulation and I want to keep only the last keyframes and delete the previous ones. Is there a way to do this? Thank you for the availability.

Comment: i don't think, that you only want to delete only the keyframes, tbh. Maybe you wanna give us some more informations, what you are going to do? Do you want a still image of the last frame? do you want to continue/start the rigid body simulation from the last frame? or do you want to manually animate the objects after the last keyframe? Because "only" deleting keyframes shouldn't be a problem at all...

Comment: Sorry for the fewer pieces of information, what I'm trying to do is keep the final model that comes out from the simulation and then make on it other kinds of operations. For example, I've just tried to assign Ifc class after the simulation but I make that the model comes back on the first simulation keyframe. So I had idea to keep the last keyframe and delete the others. I don't if I made the idea of what I'm trying to do, I hope so. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

just go to your last keyframe, then object -> rigid body -> apply transform. Then you can delete all keyframes and rigid body (if u want to)